# Drawing a CGRect by touching

Tags: objective-c, drawing, touch

I was wondering how to draw a CGRect onto an UIImageView.  Here is the code I've got but it doesn't seem to be working.  Any suggestions? touch1 and touch2 are both CGPoints and point is a CGRect.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
touch1 = [touch locationInView:self];
touch2 = [touch locationInView:self];
}
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

}    

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
touch2 = [touch locationInView:self];
point = CGRectMake(touch2.x, touch2.y, 50, 50);
[self setNeedsDisplay];
}

 - (void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blackColor].CGColor);
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, pointColor.CGColor);
CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, point);
CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFillStroke);
}
```

Comment: are you trying to draw a rectangle or a circle?  You said in your comments 'a CGRect' but in the code it says CGContextAddEllipseInRect

Comment: sorry for not specifying…at this point I'm just trying to get something to draw on the screen in general.  I have a class that is a subclass of a UIViewController which has the imageView displaying an actual image.  I want to be able to draw on that image only.

Answer (score 1):

What do you see actually happening?

A few notes:

1. You shouldn't be doing this with a UIImageView-- those are specifically intended to be containers for image files. You should just use a subclass of a regular UIView for this.
2. In your `touchesBegan`, you know that `touch1` and `touch2` will always be set to the same thing, right? You don't seem to ever be using touch1.
3. `point` is a misleading variable name for something that is a rect.
4. Your `drawRect` is not unreasonable. What is `pointColor`? If you're drawing black-on-black that might be part of the problem.

Comment: I really only need 1 touch for right now.  I eventually, after drawing it on the screen, want to be able to drag that "point" around to move it wherever I want.  "point" may be a little misleading to you as someone who isn't using this program.  pointColor is a UIColor and I've tried to draw it on the screen in general which has a white background with a picture loaded into a UIImageView.

Answer (score 0):

[Listing 3-1](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_paths/dq_paths.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH211-TPXREF101)  Code that creates an ellipse by applying a transform to a circle

```
CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1,2);
CGContextBeginPath(context);
CGContextAddArc(context, 0, 0, 25, 0, 2*M_PI, false);
CGContextStrokePath(context);
```

Lots more example code in the [Quartz2d Example](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/QuartzDemo/Listings/Quartz_QuartzCurves_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007531-Quartz_QuartzCurves_m-DontLinkElementID_26)

Answer (score 0):

I took your code only, its working for me. Just have look at it. And thanks for your code. In this sample i am drawing a rect.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect 
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();  
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);  
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blackColor].CGColor);  
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);  
    CGContextAddRect(context, rectFrame);  
    CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFillStroke);  

}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    startPoint = [touch locationInView:self];
    rectFrame.origin.x = startPoint.x;
    rectFrame.origin.y = startPoint.y;
}  
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    endPoint = [touch locationInView:self];
    rectFrame.size.width = endPoint.y - startPoint.x;
    rectFrame.size.height = endPoint.y - startPoint.x;

    [self setNeedsDisplay];
 }    

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    endPoint = [touch locationInView:self];
    rectFrame.size.width = endPoint.y - startPoint.x;
    rectFrame.size.height = endPoint.y - startPoint.x;

    [self setNeedsDisplay];
 }
```